# What are the main differences between OnEditorActionListener and OnKeyListener?

Tags: android, textview, onkeylistener

1. I would like to know what are the implications of using `TextView.OnEditorActionListener` vs `View.OnKeyListener`

This is what the docs say about `View.OnKeyListener`

> This is only useful for hardware keyboards; a software input method has no obligation to trigger this listener.

Yet I see everyone online is using it with `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER` on `EditText`s

2. I'm using a barcode scanner for input and I noticed, when triggered, it would open/close the `NavigationDrawer` (if the hardware keyboard setting is on). Is this the main difference ? An `OnKeyListener` will propagate to all views listening whilst an `OnEditorActionListener` would only trigger the `TextView`s?